# WrappedRuntimeException during processing of an XSLT transformation

Tags: java, xslt

I'm using this code to generate contents file.

```
try {
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult();
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Templates templ =  tf.newTemplates(xsltSource);
        Transformer transf = templ.newTransformer();
        for (String item: groups){
            item = item.replaceAll(" ", "-").toLowerCase();
            result.setOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path+item+".html"));
            transf.clearParameters();
            transf.setParameter("group", item);
            transf.transform(xmlSource, result);
        }
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
    throw new SinkException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
    throw new SinkException(e.getMessage());
    }
```

But on second iteration I have an exception

```
ERROR: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Read error
```

Cann't understand what is the reason?

Comment: A Templates object only need to be created once.  Try moving that out of the loop.

Comment: It didn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: Why don't you add more lines of your code? and Stacktrace reported during Exception?

Comment: What do you want being clarified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank a lot for assistance. Th error was in not properly closed Source resource.
Was:

```
Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(path+Constants.MANIFEST_FILE_NAME));
```

Fixed:

```
Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(path+Constants.MANIFEST_FILE_NAME);
```

Comment: This is why I requested more of your code. See this bit was missing from initial post. The fragment was apparently error free and there is no easy way to guess what would have h append prior to that.